# png() ignores my ggplot's element_text(size = ...) argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with ~30 different groups that I want to plot, so I wrote a function where I can make a ggplot based on a selected group. Then I ran this in a for() function to repeat it for every group and save each graph as a png so I don't have to do it manually.

Now the problem is that png() seems to be ignoring my set **text size**, and I can't just change the default size because **I want the axis text to be smaller than the rest** of the text.

Is there a way to keep the text size from my ggplot function and still automatically save all the plots as a png-file?

Here's my code (reduced to what's necessary for this question):

```
  mydata2 <- mydata[mydata$Ind == Names_CI[a,2],]
  ggplot(data = mydata2,
         aes(x = Year,
             y = Average,
             fill = Type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single')) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 35),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 35),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 30),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 35))
} 

for (i in 1:30) {
  png(file = paste('/Users/Name/Documents/R/', Names_CI[i,3], '.png', sep = ''),
  width = 1660, height = 1000)
  print(mycode(i))
  dev.off()
}
```

For explanation: Names is the table that contains all the group names, as well as their x- & y-axis labels and the png file names I want to use.

Comment: It doesn’t ignore it, but element sizing at different resolutions is highly unintuitive. I highly recommend you read the [*Plot scaling* article](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/08/taking-control-of-plot-scaling/) by Thomas Lin Pedersen, it explains the problem and shows the proper solution. The short version is: use the ‘ragg’ package and pass a `scaling` argument to `agg_png`.

Comment: Thank you, I actually managed to solve it like this!